# UPDATE one value when SELECT many

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I have a less straightforward SQL query than those I've seen when asking this question, so I was hoping to get some help with my query.

The following query selects three specific values and I need one value that isn't selected to be updated.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS, ANSI_WARNINGS, ARITHABORT ON;
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT EXP.EmpID,
  -1 * EXP.TotalAmount AS Amount,
  EXP.Name
  FROM TBL EXP
  WHERE EXP.ID IN (1, 2, 3) --this is dynamically created
  AND EXP.Status = 'APPROVED'
) AS ResultTable
```

From that query, I need to `UPDATE` the EXP.Status value to 'COMPLETE'.

How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't you just use `UPDATE`?

```
UPDATE exp
    SET EXP.Status = 'COMPLETE'
    FROM TBL EXP
    WHERE EXP.ID IN (1, 2, 3) AND
          EXP.Status = 'APPROVED';
```

Comment: Right, I should probably elaborate a little bit more. I am using that `SELECT` statement to compile a CSV file and save that file via a HTTP transaction. I need to be able to see the results of the statement.

Comment: Yes. `UPDATE` then `SELECT` the exact data that was updated.

Comment: You opened up my eyes and made me realize that I could just do both statements. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could maybe also try something like:

```
UPDATE EXP
SET EXP.Status = 'COMPLETE'
FROM TBL EXP
OUTPUT INSERTED.EmpID,-1 * INSERTED.TotalAmount AS Amount, INSERTED.Name
WHERE EXP.ID IN (1, 2, 3) AND EXP.Status = 'APPROVED';
```

Answer (score 0):

I realized I didn't need to have each statement merged into one. So, what I did was just add an `UPDATE` statement after my `SELECT` statement.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS, ANSI_WARNINGS, ARITHABORT ON;
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT EXP.EmpID,
  -1 * EXP.TotalAmount AS Amount,
  EXP.Name
  FROM TBL EXP
  WHERE EXP.ID IN (1, 2, 3) --this is dynamically created
  AND EXP.Status = 'APPROVED'
) AS ResultTable

UPDATE TBL
SET Status = 'COMPLETE'
WHERE ID IN (1, 2, 3) --same dynamically created variable as above SELECT statement
```